# How can I pass a string value from a Fragment to an Activity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app with a Fragment that contains an EditText field. When the user enters a value in the EditText field, I need to pass this value to the hosting Activity so that it can be used in other parts of the app.

I have tried using an Intent to pass the data, but this opens a new instance of the Activity, which I do not want. I have also tried using a Bundle, but I'm not sure how to access the Bundle from the Activity.

What is the best way to pass a string value from a Fragment to an Activity? Are there any code examples or tutorials that can help me achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to search by your self. [Example](https://www.google.com/search?q=pass+data+from+fragment+to+parent+activity&rlz=1C1CHZL_enIN847IN847&oq=pass+value+from+fragment+to+parent+a&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i22i30i625l2j0i390l2.10719j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Without much detail I would say that you best bet is using a shared ViewModel between the activity and the fragment.

one resource you can easily follow: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-viewmodel-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

**1. First approach**

The best approach is to use `Interface`, try to search how to pass data from `Fragment` to `Activity` using `Interface`.

**2. Second approach**

This approach is to use `ViewModel` like the example mentioned above https://stackoverflow.com/a/75472219/11170352

**3. Third approach**

This is the laziest approach follow this example

> YourFragment

```
// Get a reference to the hosting Activity
YourActivity yourActivity = (YourActivity) getActivity();

// Call a public method in the Activity to pass the data
yourActivity.setData(myData);
```

> YourActivity

```
public void setData(String data) {
   // Do something with the data
}
```

Note that this approach assumes that the hosting Activity is of a specific class (YourActivity in this example). If you need to use this approach with multiple Activities, you may want to add some checks to ensure that the Activity is the correct type before casting it.